# How to select two table (document) value at a time by user id in mongoose?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am using NodeJs, ExpressJs with Mongodb and Mongoose. I want to select two document's value by user id.

I have three model User, Academic and Career. I have made a relation with Academic and Career schema by _id of User schema. I have saved some values in these documents. Now i want to select academic and career's document value by user id.

## Model

```
 // user model
    const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
        name: {type: String},
        email: {type: String},
    });
    const user = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);

    // academic model
    const academicSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
        academicLevel: {type: String},
        passYear: {type: Number},
        user: {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: 'User'
        }
    });
    const academic = mongoose.model('Academic', academicSchema);

    // career model
    const careerSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
        jobTitle: {type: String},
        company: {type: String},
        user: {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: 'User'
        }
    });
    const career = mongoose.model('Career', careerSchema);
```

## documents

```
// user documents

_id: objectId("5d0df6a4134d4d295ca9f212")
name: "John Doe"
email: "john@gmail.com"

_id: objectId("5d0e70a6c87ca528c0a79a0f")
name: "Mark Boucher"
email: "mark@gmail.com"


// academic documents

_id: objectId("5d60bc7188a8ef3648b8e8cf")
academicLevel: "Master"
passYear: "2018"
user: objectId("5d0e70a6c87ca528c0a79a0f")

_id: objectId("5d60d56f0cf9af32901cb2aa")
academicLevel: "Bachelor"
passYear: "2016"
user: objectId("5d0e70a6c87ca528c0a79a0f")

// career documents

_id: objectId("5d60bc1d88a8ef3648b8e8ce")
jobTitle: "Software Engineer"
company: "Daffodil Software Ltd."
user: objectId("5d0e70a6c87ca528c0a79a0f")
```

## nodejs

```
router.get('/getInfoById', async (req, res) => {
    const user = await User
    .find(req.query.id)
    .select()

    res.send(user);
})
```

How to get values from two documents (academic and career) by user id. Thanks.

Comment: Do you want two different queries or want  single query to get the solution ?

Comment: i want single query

Comment: Which version MongoDB are you use ? Do you need aggregation query ?

Comment: version:  4.0.9. I don't know about aggregation query. I am new in Mongodb and mongoose

Comment: i think best practice is using 2 queries, as suggested in an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For what I've read in the docs, I think what you are looking for is something like so:

```
const career = await Career.find({ user: user._id});
const academics = await Academics.find({ user: user._id});
```

Or if you want to execute both queries at the same time:

```
const careerOperation = Career.find({ user: user._id});
const academicsOperation = Academics.find({ user: user._id});

const [
    career, 
    academics
] = await Promise.all([career.exec(), academics.exec()]);
```

Hope to have helped!

Comment: When I discovered it, I figured it to be so awesome. But beware if you have more than two elements in the array, I would suggest putting it in a variable and breaking after each comma

Comment: Two years ago I find a solution with this syntax. From that day, I always use only this syntax for promise resolve. Thanks bro.

Comment: @VitorRibeiro I have used your solution code in this way: router.get('/getInfoById', async (req, res) => {
    const career = Career.find({user: req.query.user});
    const academic = Academic.find({ user: req.query.user});

    await Promise.all([career.exec(), academic.exec()]);

    res.send(career);
    res.send(academic);
})

but i got an error. error is : UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON

Comment: I forgot to add something to my answer, I'll update it right away! Only one note, do not call res.send twice on the same request, is best for you to call it once nesting what you want to pass in a object: res.send({career, academics});

Comment: @VitorRibeiro you beauty! thanks a lot brother. I have spent a lot of time for this. At least i got this.

Answer (score 2):

Since `Mongoose` is used here: This can achieved using [**Populate**](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html). `populate` is pretty similar/analogues to what you would achieve via [**$lookup**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) aggregation in pure mongo.

**An alternative option:** If you would adjust your schemas like this to really leverage `Mongoose`.

```
//user model
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: { type: String },
  email: { type: String },
  career: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "Career"
  },
  academic: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "Academic"
  }
});

//academics and career can be array of documents as well -if required
const user = mongoose.model("User", userSchema);

// academic model
const academicSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  academicLevel: { type: String },
  passYear: { type: Number }
});
const academic = mongoose.model("Academic", academicSchema);

// career model
const careerSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  jobTitle: { type: String },
  company: { type: String }
});
const career = mongoose.model("Career", careerSchema);
```

**Populate query:** To get user's academics and career docs

```
const user = await User.find({ _id: requestedUserId })
  .populate("academic")
  .populate("career")
  .exec();
```

NOTE: `requestedUserId` is the user id that to be filtered upon.

Answer (score 1):

This is the simplest query we can make for find user with given query Id

```
router.get('/getInfoById/:id', async (req, res) => {
     const user = await User.aggregate([
           { $match: { _id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.query.id) }},
           { $lookup: {
              from: "career",
              localField: "_id",
              foreignField: "user",
              as: "careers"
           }},
           { $lookup: {
              from: "academic",
              localField: "_id",
              foreignField: "user",
              as: "academics"
           }}
        ])
    res.send(user);
});
```