# Mongoose populate join multiple table?

Tags: node.js, mongoose, mongoose-populate

Suppose,
I have two tables: A and B. Both tables have `_id` and `name`

**Schema:**

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const p= {
  seller: { type: "ObjectId", ref: "A" },
 
};

const pSchema = new mongoose.Schema(p);

module.exports = mongoose.model("p", pSchema);
```

**Model:**

```
 let response = await pSchema
    .find(where) //where contains _id
    .populate({ path: "seller", select: { name: 1 } })
```

This will fetch `_id` and `name` from the `A` table.

**What I want ?**

If data not found at the `A` table ...then automatically search At `B` table and find out desired data and show both results of `A` and `B`.Like join two tables and fetch data from those two tables.

How can I achieve that using mongoose?

Comment: `Mongoose` allows multiple path population [`Mongoose populate`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html#populating-multiple-paths) and could work like this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57834117/6082280) as long as `B` ref is defined in schema.

Comment: B ref is not defined in schema. @ambianBeing